# Scheme - Recursion : Sum consecutive elements of a list

Tags: list, recursion, scheme

I'm trying to write a function using Scheme that :

1. take a list of integers with more than two elements  as a parameter
2. sum the n-th-element and (n+1)-th-element
3. return this list

Result should be as follows :

```
> (SumNeighbors (list 1 2 3 4))
(3 5 7)
```

I think I get the way to add elements but my recursion is totally wrong...

```
(define (SumNeighbors lst)
  (if (not (null? (cdr lst)))
      (append (list (+ (car lst) (car (cdr lst)))) (SumNeighbors (cdr lst)))))
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this problem follows a well-known pattern. I'll give you some hints, it'll be more fun if you find the answer by your own means:

```
(define (SumNeighbors lst)
  (if <???>                    ; if there's only one element left
      <???>                    ; we're done, return the empty list
      (cons                    ; otherwise call `cons`
       (+ <???> <???>)         ; add first and second elements
       (SumNeighbors <???>)))) ; and advance recursion
```

Notice the following:

- Your solution is lacking the base case - what happens when the list we're traversing only has one element left? it's time to finish the recursion! and because we're building a list as the output, what should be the value returned?
- We normally use `cons` to build an output list, not `append`. That's the natural way to build a list
- The part of this procedure that falls outside the solution template is the fact that we stop when there's a single elment left in the list, not when the list is empty (as is the usual case)

You'll see that many procedures that iterate over an input list and return a list as output follow the same solution template, it's very important that you learn how and why this works, it's the foundation for writing solutions to other similar problems.

Comment: thanks a lot, it work !
(define (SumNeighbors lst)
  (if (null? (cdr lst))
      null             
      (cons
       (+ (car lst) (car (cdr lst)))
       (SumNeighbors (cdr lst)))))

Answer (score 1):

```
#!r6rs
(import (except (rnrs base) map)
        (only (srfi :1) map))

(define (sum-neighbors lst)
  (map + lst (cdr lst)))
```

The higher order function `map` as defined in [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#map) supports uneven lenght arguments. It will stop at the shortest list.

If you call `(sum-neighbors  '(1 2 3 4))` it will become `(map + (1 2 3 4) (2 3 4))` which is the same as `(cons (+ 1 2) (cons (+ 2 3) (cons (+ 3 4) '())))`